# Control html5 canvas animation speed by jquery ui slider

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, animation, html5-canvas

I'm trying to build a interactive html5 canvas animation. so i'm trying to control animation speed based on jquery ui slider value.
**when slider value changes automatically it will reflect in canvas animation**.

i'm beginner in jquery and canvas animation, so kindly describe possible way in code samples or reference materials.

[Here is my link for codepen](http://codepen.io/rajumax/pen/gpopeY)

```
$(function() {
    $( "#slider" ).slider({
      orientation: "vertical",
      range: "min",
      min: 0,
      max: 100,
      value: 60,
      slide: function( event, ui ) {
        $( "#amount" ).val( ui.value );
      }
    });
    $( "#amount" ).val( $( "#slider" ).slider( "value" ) );
  });


//canvas animation

 var canvas = document.getElementById("stage");
  var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
  var speed= 2;     // get jquery ui slider value
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The important thing:

```
clearInterval(t);
t = setInterval(DrawCanvas, 120 / ui.value);
```

Copy pastable code:

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="btn"></div>
  <input id="amount"type="text" />
  <div id="slider" style="height:200px;"></div> 
  <canvas id="stage" width="289" height="289" style="border:2px solid black;top: 20%;  left: 50%;" ></canvas>
</div>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.2/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" />
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.2/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<script>
var t;              // this will be the setInterval object.  We will control the speed with this
var factor = 120;   // 120ms / the slider value; default: 120/4 = 30
//ui slider 
$( "#slider" ).slider({
  orientation: "vertical",
  range: "min",
  min: 1,
  max: 10,
  value: 4,
  slide: function( event, ui ) {
    $( "#amount" ).val( ui.value );
    clearInterval(t);
    t = setInterval(DrawCanvas, 120 / ui.value);
  }
});
$( "#amount" ).val( $( "#slider" ).slider( "value" ) );
var speedvar= document.getElementById("amount").value;
var canvas = document.getElementById("stage");
var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
var speed= speedvar;  //get value form jquery ui slider   
var Ball = new Array();
var BallNow;
var SumMove = 50;
var posX, posY, r, TheAngle, TheSpeed, MoveX, MoveY;

for(i=0; i<SumMove; i++) {
  posX = r + Math.random() * (canvas.width - r*2);
  posY = r + Math.random() * (canvas.height - r*2);
  r = 5;
  TheAngle = Math.random() * 360;
  TheSpeed = speed;
  console.log(TheSpeed);
  MoveX = Math.cos(Math.PI/180 * TheAngle) * TheSpeed;
  MoveY = Math.sin(Math.PI/180 * TheAngle) * TheSpeed;

  BallNow = {x: posX, y: posY, r:r, MoveX: MoveX, MoveY: MoveY};
  Ball.push(BallNow);
}
t = setInterval(DrawCanvas, 30);

function DrawCanvas() {
  ctx.clearRect(0,0,canvas.width,canvas.height);
  for(i=0; i<SumMove; i++) {
    Ball[i].x += Ball[i].MoveX;
    Ball[i].y += Ball[i].MoveY;
    if(Ball[i].x + Ball[i].r >= canvas.width || Ball[i].x - Ball[i].r <= 0) {
      Ball[i].MoveX = -Ball[i].MoveX;
    }
    if(Ball[i].y + Ball[i].r >= canvas.height || Ball[i].y - Ball[i].r <= 0) {
      Ball[i].MoveY = -Ball[i].MoveY;
    }
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.fillStyle = "#042fcf";
    ctx.arc(Ball[i].x, Ball[i].y, Ball[i].r, 0, Math.PI*2,false);
    ctx.fill();
    ctx.closePath();
  }
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

instead of using setInterval to animate the canvas... Try using setTimeout inside your animation function and set the speed in between frames to your slider value.

What you have:

```
setInterval(DrawCanvas,30);
function DrawCanvas(){}
```

what you should try:

```
function DrawCanvas(){
    setTimeout(DrawCanvas, speed);
}
DrawCanvas();
```

Basically, setTimeout will run just once, and after set time, so you can change the time between frames dynamically.

On the other hand, setInterval will run automatically every set time frame, so you cannot change its timing without stopping it first.